# best practice dispose parentWeb on feature activated, how to fix it in this scenario?

Tags: 2010, dispose

I am getting a warning from the spdisposecheck in one method I executed on the feature activated event.

```
private void CopyAttendees(SPWeb currentWeb)
  {
   try
    {
      SPWeb parentWeb = currentWeb.ParentWeb;
      SPList parentWebAttendeeList = parentWeb.GetSafeListByName(MeetingsCommon.Constants.LISTS_ATTENDEES_NAME);
      SPList currentWebAttendeeList = currentWeb.GetSafeListByName(MeetingsCommon.Constants.LISTS_ATTENDEES_NAME);
      foreach (SPListItem itemParentWebAttendeeList in parentWebAttendeeList.Items)
       {
        SPListItem itemCurrentWebAttendeeList = currentWebAttendeeList.Items.Add();
        itemParentWebAttendeeList.MapFieldValue(MeetingsCommon.Constants.FIELDS_TEXT_TITLE_NAME, itemCurrentWebAttendeeList);
        itemParentWebAttendeeList.MapFieldValue(MeetingsCommon.Constants.FIELDS_ATTENDEEROLE_NAME, itemCurrentWebAttendeeList);
        itemParentWebAttendeeList.MapFieldValue(MeetingsCommon.Constants.FIELDS_ATTENDEEATTENDANCE_NAME, itemCurrentWebAttendeeList);
        itemCurrentWebAttendeeList.SystemUpdate();
       }
     }
   catch (Exception ex)
    {
     throw;
    }
 }

 public override void FeatureActivated(SPFeatureReceiverProperties properties)
   {                
      Logger.LogDebug("NLMeetingsSiteConfigNLBDMeetingEventReceiver", "FeatureActivated(SPFeatureReceiverProperties properties)", "BEGIN");
      try
        {
          string siteUrl = (properties.Feature.Parent as SPWeb).Url;
          SPSecurity.RunWithElevatedPrivileges(() =>
           {
             using (SPSite currentSite = new SPSite(siteUrl))
              {
                using (SPWeb currentWeb = currentSite.OpenWeb())
                 {
                   SetCustomMasterPage(currentWeb);
                   ModifyHomePage(currentWeb);
                   CopyAttendees(currentWeb);
                   SetSecurity(currentWeb);
                   ConfigureWeb(currentWeb);
                 }
              }
           }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In [this post](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa973248%28v=office.12%29.aspx) you can find this:

> An earlier version of this article recommended that the calling
>   application should dispose of the SPWeb.ParentWeb. This is no longer
>   the official guidance. The dispose cleanup is handled automatically by
>   the SharePoint framework.

Also you can find this note:

> This best practice addresses the issue identified by the SharePoint
>   Dispose Checker Tool as SPDisposeCheckID_170.

and this example:

```
using (SPSite site = new SPSite(http://localhost)) 
{
    using (SPWeb web = site.OpenWeb())
    {
        SPList list = web.Lists["Announcements"];
        SPWeb parentWeb = list.ParentWeb; //No explicit dispose required.
    }
}
```

As you can see some times dispose checker works incorrect.

Answer (score 0):

In your example you cannot do any harm in disposing of the web. The golden rule is "Did you create the web", i.e. you have based everything off a brand new site/web created on the URL of the feature parent which is a safe way of doing things. Any further webs can be safely disposed of because they only exist due to your code.